# Django Save Excel to desktop

Tags: jquery, python, django, excel

So, my problem I suppose is quite easy, but I have ... some issue with it :)

So in my application written in Django I invoke creating Excel file using Ajax like this :

```
            $.ajax({
                url: '/ajax-send-xls-desktop/',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: "application/vnd.ms-excel",
                data: JSON.stringify(data_xls),
                dataType: 'text',
                success: function(result) {
                    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + result);
                }
            });
```

In my backend I create Excel file and return response like this one :

```
        response = HttpResponse(mimetype="application/vnd.ms-excel")
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=opispozycji.xls'
        response['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8'
        book.save(response)
```

Everything I received is a lot of characters :

```
    N*8X"��1���Arial1���Arial1���Arial1���Arial1���Arial1���Arial1���Arial1���Arial
�General���� �� ���� �� ���� �� ���� �� ���� �� ���� �� ���� �� ���� �� ���� �� ���� ��
���� �� ���� �� ���� �� ���� �� ���� �� ���� �� �� �� �� �� �� �� ���`��Opis pozycji��
PDane wygnerowane przez Interzam - Internetowa Platforma Zarzdzania Zam�wieniamiSIDCPV
```

Can anyone confirm that the problem lies in charset encoding ?

Comment: Can you save the stream to disk and validate that you have a correct Excel file?

Comment: Yes i can save stream to disk, but I do know why I must on my own add .xls extension to file despite of specify correct mimetype. When I open Excel file, it's content in some part is quite good (which I would like to receive) but there is a lot of signs that it should be there...

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
response = HttpResponse(mimetype="application/ms-excel")
response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % "excel.xls"
book.save(response)
return response
```

i have just link to view url and in result dialog shown. With ajax call it cant be done...

**update:**

I found a workaround solution (iframe with form used) for case where you need to dynamically request file here - [Download a file by jQuery.Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax). You can use plugin created by @JohnCulviner - http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/ or my little function `ajax_download`:

```
// creates iframe and form in it with hidden field,
// then submit form with provided data
// url - form url
// data - data to form field
// input_name - form hidden input name

function ajax_download(url, data, input_name) {
    var $iframe,
        iframe_doc,
        iframe_html;

    if (($iframe = $('#download_iframe')).length === 0) {
        $iframe = $("<iframe id='download_iframe'" +
                    " style='display: none' src='about:blank'></iframe>"
                   ).appendTo("body");
    }

    iframe_doc = $iframe[0].contentWindow || $iframe[0].contentDocument;
    if (iframe_doc.document) {
        iframe_doc = iframe_doc.document;
    }

    iframe_html = "<html><head></head><body><form method='POST' action='" +
                  url +"'>" +
                  "<input type=hidden name='" + input_name + "' value='" +
                  JSON.stringify(data) +"'/></form>" +
                  "</body></html>";

    iframe_doc.open();
    iframe_doc.write(iframe_html);
    $(iframe_doc).find('form').submit();
}
```

in your case (with click event for example):

```
$('#someid').on('click', function() {
    ajax_download('/ajax-send-xls-desktop/', data_xls, 'data');
});
```

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately I have the same issue... maybe this is related with charset ?

Comment: Hm nothing changed...the same issue ;/

Comment: Nice! I will check @JohnCulviner plugin later, but when I used your solution i have an error : Uncaught ReferenceError: ext is not defined . This piece of code use ExtJS ?

Comment: @GarciaPL no, only jquery, function is working im checked myself on my project

Comment: I had an issue on Chrome with some extension. In Opera only what i an receive is POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/ajax-send-xls-desktop/ 404 (NOT FOUND) ...

Comment: @GarciaPL just checked in chrome and firefox - all ok

Comment: Unfortunately, I have still problem with ext which is not defined. I read that error is related with AdBlock plugin, but when I disabled it the problem still occurs. And ajax method is not found ;/ weird

Answer (score 0):

The [Data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) mentions base 64 encoding as an option. The alternative is doing the relevant character encoding. I suggest you base 64 encode the data. [Here is a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript) which will help you do that.

Comment: are you sure it's possible to use Excel like this?

Comment: Maybe ;) I use those two tutorials : http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/10/export-table-data-to-excel-using-jquery.html and https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2233/

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually need to use Ajax? It seems like it is overcomplicating things.

I have excel downloads in my application, but they are standard Django views. Most of them are class based generic views, where I have overridden the render_to_response method and set the content type with excel.

So I have a standard ListView of my object to generate HTML, and and ExcelListView, which overrides the render to response method, to write an excel rather than passing it to an HTML template.

```
class ViewToExcel():
    """
    This class will implement the excel writing functionality, by overwriting the render_to_response method
    """
    headings2attrributes = {}  # empty default

    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        """
        Returns a response with a an excel sheet.
        """
        self.generate_headings()   # specific to my application

        wbk = xlwt.Workbook()
        sheet = wbk.add_sheet('sheet 1')

        # Create the HttpResponse object with the appropriate CSV header.
        response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/vnd.ms-excel')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=Report.xls'

       row_num = 0
       col_num = 0 

       ## write row of headings
       for hd_att in self.headings2attrributes :
            sheet.write(row_num, col_num , hd_att[0])
            col_num += 1
            row_num += 1

      object_list = self.get_queryset()

    # write rows of data ## again, this is fairly specific to my implementation
    for object  in object_list:   ## go through each object instance in queryset
        self.write_object_row(sheet, row_num, 0 , object)
        row_num += 1
    wbk.save(response)    
    return response



class MyView(ListView):
    """
    This will produce the standard HTML page (which should contain a link to the excel download)
    """
    context_object_name = "my_list"
    template_name = "sequencing/MyView.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
       """
       get your objects and populate a queryset / querydict here
       """
        ...        
        ...
        return MyObjects.all().filter(blah, blah= blah)


class MyExcelView( ViewToExcel , MyView):
    """
    This view will subclass both the ViewToExcel class as well as MyView. 
    When it is called it will reuse the get_queryset method from MyView, but will use RenderToResponse from ViewToExcel - producing excel response, rather than HTML
    The way I have implemented it is that the MyExcelView provides HeadingsToAttributes dictionary, which is used to write the excel. 
    """       
    headings2attrributes_template = [
        ['heading', 'attribbute' ]  , 
        ['heading_2', 'callable' ],
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this code but unfortunately this one can not be placed in my project. I must use Ajax. I also found this piece of code (https://bitbucket.org/ljean/django-excel-export/src/11fe78248745f7c9c701cad289484598b4a5f8d2/views.py) which I currently use but it doesn't work ;/